# What are you hiding behind your back vs behind yourself

Tags: word-usage

I saw my son holding something very small and he didn't want to show it.While he was going to his room I said :

***What are you hiding behind your back.***

***What are you hiding behind yourself.***

Which one is correct?

Thank you.

Comment: I think the difference between them would be if you were actually holding it or not. Behind your back-standing in front of/hiding from visual and behind yourself-holding/hiding from visual

Comment: This is a valid ELU question, but I'd have liked to see it on Parenting.SE. There, they might have said neither; instead say, "What have you got there?" to avoid grammatical technicalities and to reinforce the concept that they can hide nothing from the all seeing eyes of you, the parent.

Answer (score 2):

Either is technically "correct," but I believe the first to be more common. I could say, for example, that I hid the bag behind my back or that I hid the bag behind myself. Either is correct, but what is your meaning? In the first instance, you are more specifically stating just where you have the bag (I'm not hiding it behind my right foot, for example).

Comment: I edited my question. He just holding something very tiny.